# Sun Global Desktop - Tunnelling existing X window session

Tags: solaris, remote-access, tunneling, x11

I'm evaluating Sun Global Desktop as a remote connectivity solution. One thing that is not clear to me is this. When the user connects through SGD he gets a local X session and he runs his application on whatever remote machine he wants to use.

For the sake of this question let's say that the remote machines run Solaris and the PC at home is running windows or Linux.

What if he had an existing X session on a specific machine? Would it be possible to forward/redirect that to that he can see it remotely?

The scenario is this: user left his machine logged in with a running X session at the office. He's at home, he can connect and run new programs but he has no access to the existing X session at the office, he can see the processes but not their windows, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, this is a limitation of X; you can't move windows between sessions.

However, you could use a tool like [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) to accomplish what you're trying to do. It works a bit like GNU Screen, allowing you to detach a window from one session and attach it to a different session. It's written in Python so it will run without having to compile any source code, although you may find it difficult to make it work with the X server Sun ships.

Comment: If trying Xpra, try [this fork](http://xpra.org/) which is more up to date

Answer (score 0):

Your statement "*When the user connects through SGD he gets a local X session and he runs his application on whatever remote machine he wants to use.*" is slightly incorrect.

The X session isn't local but is running on the SGD server. Between the local workstation (PC at home running Windows or Linux in your example) and the SGD server, the AIP protocol is used, not X11.

If suspend/resume is allowed, a user can move from one site to the other and resume the X applications in the state they were the last time they were used. So in you scenario, it suffice the user to launch the required applications through SGD to get access to them from both the office and home locations.